# Where can I learn a preprocessor include algorithm?

Tags: php, parsing, include, preprocessor

I am writing a PHP preprocessor for C as an experiment, and I want to create an include notation like:

```
//? include("myfile.h");
```

I am struggling wrapping my head around a good way to deal with recursive inclusion.

For example:

**a.c**:

```
//? include ("a.h");

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
    return 0;
}
```

**a.h**:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
//? include ("b.h");
//? include ("c.h");
#endif /* A_H */
```

**b.h**:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#endif /* B_H */
```

**c.h**:

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

#endif /* C_H */
```

I want this parser to take in an initial file I want to preprocess, and output the result, such as(yes I cut/pasted):

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#endif /* B_H */
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

#endif /* C_H */
#endif /* A_H */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
    return 0;
}
```

through something like:

```
php parser.php infile.c outfile.c
```

I am thinking about how I should go about implementing such a parser but I am struggling expressing how this behavior works.

This is my current thinking process, which it trivial but gives me a place to start:

```
<?php

$infile = $argv[1];
$outfile = $argv[2];

$startFile = file_get_contents($infile);

/* begin transformations */
function transform($t)
{
    /* not sure how to express the transformation */

    return $t;
}

$output = transform($startFile);
/* end of transformations */

file_put_contents('out.c', $outfile); 
?>
```

I know the include pattern is:

```
$regex = "/[\/][\/][?](?:\s+)(?:include)(?:\s*)(?:[(]\s*)(?:(?:[\"](.*)[\"])|(?:['](.*)[']))(?:\s*)[)];/";
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It's not a C specific question, it's language neutral preprocessor issue. It may have been a text file with [$_include("hello.txt")_$]. I just happen to be applying it into c files.

Comment: "Where can I learn" is categorically an off-topic question. You should rephrase that and simply ask "how to do it".

Comment: Good point. Modified.